# What are limitation of Swift on Linux?

Tags: linux, swift

Apple release swift as open source so,any **IDE** available to Implement on **Linux**?

Comment: Swift is a programming language. Xcode is an IDE. Apple only open sourced the language, not the completely separate IDE.

Comment: i want to know that, any IDE for implement it on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another user correctly stated, Xcode is an IDE, and Swift is a language.  This is like asking: can we use Microsoft Visual Studio on Linux, since C and C++ can be used on Linux?  Maybe in the future - yes, but not any time soon.

As for the limitations of Swift on Linux, I think the most important ones to note are:

1) The port of Swift to Linux is brand new.  There are bugs.  In fact, some people can't even use it on Linux as advertised.  I could, but this is probably dependent on the specific installation of Linux.  Mine is Ubuntu 14.04, but for others it failed on the same OS, Ubuntu 14.04.  Not good.

2) For now we cannot use Swift on Linux to write apps for iOS and other Apple platforms.

3) A lot of frameworks/software libraries that can be used to program in Swift on Mac OS X using Xcode won't be available on Linux.

Swift on Linux is, as I understand it, intended for people to learn this new high-level cool language, so they can eventually start programming on Mac OS X or write Linux applications faster, taking advantage of the Swift language features.